# cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails for my sql database

Tags: sql, constraints

I have created some tables in for my database. I have been struggling with this error for a few hours now and I dont know how to resolve it.

> INSERT INTO ark.playerfood VALUES ('1', '3') Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ark`.`playerfood`, CONSTRAINT `fk_PlayerFood_Player` FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`) REFERENCES `player` (`playerID`))

[first one][image: 1]

[second one][image: 2]

[third one][image: 3]

Comment: oh , please paste plain text instead of screenshot

Comment: Please don't use images for code blocks, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for formatting code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , the error message is clear , you are violating the foreign key means that its one or combination of below issue:

1. you don't have a record in ark.player with playerid = 1
2. and/or you don't have a record in ark.food with foodID = 3

the error message is complaining for the first case , but I pointed out the second point as it might show up if you don't have values in there.

Comment: Oh. I had my insert statements in the wrong order.... I'm new to this so I didn't know. Thank you for helping because I didn't understand the error.